# Compile C++ native activity with NDK

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, android.mk

I create Android native activity project based on "*native-activity*" project in NDK. In this project `android_main` function is implemented in *main.c* file and it compiles and run without any issues.

Now I wants to implement some C++ routines in this file and to do that, as a first step I change *main.c* file to *main.cpp* and change `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` entry in *Android.mk* to `main.cpp`.

After this change I got following error at the compilation:

```
make.exe: *** No rule to make target `jni/main.c', needed by `obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/native-activity/main.o'.  Stop.
```

Also *Android.mk* file in this project contain following entries:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := native-activity
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -landroid -lEGL -lGLESv1_CM -lGLESv2
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
```

What was the possible cause for this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete your obj directory from workspace and rebuild. Sometimes eclipse clean is not working and failed to delete obj files.

Comment: Thanks! As you said, once I delete obj directory it got resolved.